# Optimising query performance using R, odbc and Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, dbi

I'm looking to collect about 300K rows of data from my SQL Server.

My query runs in approx. 20 seconds using DBeaver (uses a JDBC driver) Vs. my query from R using DBI/odbc which takes more than 15 mins.

Are there any additional parameters I can specify in my connection string that would speed up the collection of this data?

Here is my connections string:

```
db_conn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
  Driver = "SQL Server",
  Server = "server_name_cls.xx.yy.abc.com",
  Database = "MySchema",
  UID = "myID",
  PWD = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password"),
  Trusted_Connection = "Yes",
  Port = 1433,
  applicationIntent = "readonly"
)
```

Comment: I've worked a lot to optimize my queries against a SQL Server, and not once have I seen an identical query's performance vary by an order of magnitude like that. I suggest you confirm that the query is identical, any parameters are passed in an identical fashion, connection tunnel is the same (i.e., same network connection type), etc. I have found in the past that I was confounding other components of R processing in the benchmarking, so ensure that your "20 minutes" is not including other steps. Finally, for huge volumes, I tend to prefer using `sqlcmd.exe` (with caveats) for speed.

Comment: just a minor addition to what @r2evans as discussed.. Are you pulling many `date` columns by chance? these can be pulled into R as character, slowing down the pull.

Comment: @langtang yes, of the 11 columns I'm pulling, 2 are date columns and as you mentioned when  these finally land in R they are character columns. Is there some transformation I need to apply to these columns?

Comment: It seems strange that only two columns on 300,000 rows would cause such as slow down, but you can do `qry="select convert(datetime,col) as col from table"`.. pull should be faster... If you are doing this in dplyr, you can `df %>% mutate(col=sql("convert(datetime, col)"))`